# Skip to the next loop if object is a list

Tags: r, list

I need to check if an object is a `list` if yes skip to the next loop.

```
if(is.list(x)) next
```

The above code is throwing the error below

```
Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Comment: can you add a little bit more code to give context? R is telling you that your `next` statement doesn't occur within a `for` loop.

Comment: Can somebody please explain why we're talking about `list`s yet have a [tag:dplyr] tag that requires at a minimum some form of `data.frame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this dummy data

```
my_list <- list(1,2,3 , list(12) , 5 , list(23))
```

You can use this `for` loop

```
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
    if(is.list(my_list[[i]])) next
    else my_list[[i]] <- my_list[[i]] + 100
}
```

- Output

```
[[1]]
[1] 101

[[2]]
[1] 102

[[3]]
[1] 103

[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 12


[[5]]
[1] 105

[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] 23
```

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. `x` is a variable generated inside a loop and can be a `list` or `data.frame`. I need to check if `x` is a `list` if yes skip to the next loop.

Comment: would you attach your code to let others help ?